# How to install nfs-utils in Kubuntu 21.10? The obvious command doesn't work

Tags: software-installation, nfs

How can I install **nfs-utils** in Kubuntu 21.10? The obvious command **sudo apt install nfs-utils** doesn't work for me, though I can install **nfs-common** that way.

Comment: Doesn't work as what ? Does that throw an error ?

Comment: I think it's `libnfs-utils` what you are looking for...

Comment: Even 20.04 LTS doesn't have `nfs-utils`.  I think that @mook765 is correct.

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/impish/libnfs , do not invent non-existing package names.

Comment: The name nfs-utils appeared in  the instructions for accessing a Synology network attached storage unit. I didn't invent it. It may have appeared elsewhere as well.

Comment: I wonder if there's some way to make nfs-utils an alias for libnfs-utils.

Comment: I use NFS all the time as I don't like the Samba bugs.  All I have had to install was the `nfs-common` to make it work right.

Comment: For me, the problem showed up when I tried to do a mount.  I got a complaint that the filesystem couldn't be identified, even though the mount command included  "-t nfs". Now that I've installed libnfs-utils, I can't reproduce it.